# Materialize CSS - how to keep color modifications separate from NPM module?

Tags: css, npm, sass, materialize

I'm using the npm module of `materialize-css` (0.100-2) in an electron application. Npm modules are not tracked in git. I have made changes to the SASS components, specifically these files:

```
node_modules/
+-- materialize-css/
    +-- sass/
        materialize.scss    <-- changes
        +-- components/
            ...
            _color.scss     <-- changes
            _variables.scss <-- changes
            _palette.css    <-- new file I added
```

I've compiled the new `materialize.css` in `node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css` using the instructions found here: http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html and everything works well.

However, I'm planning to upgrade to 1.0.0-beta and need to keep my modifications in git. Any ideas or best practices on how to keep my modifications separate from the SASS files but still include them when compiling the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change directly your `node_modules` files, instead of that you should define another file in your project root, for example: `app.scss`

```
/
  ...
  node_modules/
  ...
  app.css
  package.json
```

As it is shown right here: http://materializecss.com/sass.html, you can now change your pallete and so, in your `app.scss` file:

```
// Import materialize-css
@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize";

$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: false !default;
$primary-color-dark: false !default;
@if not $primary-color-light {
  $primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%);
}
@if not $primary-color-dark {
  $primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%);
}
$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;

$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;

/*** More variables not shown here.. ***/
```

**Note** You will need to add a `sass` compiler.

Comment: Yefferson Marín: Thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to work. :-( Here's a gist with my customisation per your answer: https://gist.github.com/jfix/b0bb5bf2ff1d7a38824e5bd5171102e5 The SASS compilation works fine, but in the end I still get the official red and green. :-( Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: Refere to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jfix/b0bb5bf2ff1d7a38824e5bd5171102e5) to see the proper way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Yefferson Marín! As discussed on Gitter.im, I finally decided to go the way of not using the npm module, but to include the SASS and CSS files in my code base, as described here: https://medium.com/@mancebo128/how-to-properly-add-custom-colors-to-materialize-css-52e5e4c58d58 Thanks again for your help and patience!